# Some input files use or override a deprecated API

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, java-wireless-toolkit

I just downloaded the new LWUIT 1.5 and when I compiled my project then I saw in the output trace these lines:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I use Sun Java ME SDK 3.0

So how to make the `-Xlint` recompilation?

Comment: Are you using `Obfuscation` in your project?

Comment: @bharath How to know if I use Obfuscation in my project ?

Comment: Open project properties and look on obfuscation.

Comment: The obfuscation level is `Off`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling issue in NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293410/compiling-issue-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

according to comments in older SO question, "-Xlint in NetBeans is set under project properties, run or compile options" - see details here: [Compiling issue in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293410/compiling-issue-in-netbeans)

There is also a [thread at Netbeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic39838.html). They say,

> Go to the Compiling section of the Project Properties. These is a check box labeled "Report use of deprecated API". Checking that will turn on -Xlint.

Answer (score 4):

Implement this code below and outside of compileOptions bracket located in the build.gradle (Module) and implement this code. This should resolve the issue.

```
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
            options.compilerArgs <<"-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

Your error will be solved if you replace the deprecated functions. IDEs like Android Studio will show them with squiggly lines, some IDEs will suggest replacements you can easily use.

Comment: Hi, this answer lacks details. Please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your post accordingly.